# Component "Bearingfriction" leads to singular inconsistent scalar system

Tags: simulation, modeling, modelica, openmodelica, dymola

I am quite new to using Dymola and am currently working on creating a mechanical model for a robotic arm. I am using the block 'Source - Position' to impose the position of the joints. I want to introduce friction and intend to use a table to model it (angular velocity : torque). Therefore, I chose the 'BearingFriction' component.
My problem is that for certain input position values I get the following error:

```
Error: Singular inconsistent scalar system for bearingFriction.sa = ((if bearingFriction.locked then 0 else (if bearingFriction.startForward then -1.34 else (if bearingFriction.startBackward then 1.34 else (if pre(bearingFriction.mode) == 1 then -1.34 else 1.34))))-der)/( -(if bearingFriction.locked then 0 else 1.0)) = 19.8524/-0
Fixed point iterating to handle problem.
```

I am stuck on this problem, I tried for example to change solver, tolerance, and interpolation method of the table but with no result.
I share with you my code (with an example of values for which I have the error):

```
model Test
  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.Inertia inertia(J=2)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-40,14},{-20,34}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.BearingFriction bearingFriction(tau_pos=[0,1; 10,1.5; 20,
        2.1; 40,2.6; 100,4.8; 150,5.1; 300,5.8; 600,6], peak=1.34)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-4,14},{16,34}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.Inertia inertia1(J=3)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{74,14},{94,34}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.IdealGear idealGear(ratio=20)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{36,14},{56,34}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Sources.Position position(exact=true)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-82,14},{-62,34}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.ContinuousClock continuousClock
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-160,14},{-140,34}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds combiTable1Ds(
    table=[0.0,70.2029; 0.00482,70.2029; 0.00964,70.2029; 0.01446,70.2014; 0.01928,70.197;
        0.0241,70.1876; 0.02892,70.1663],
    columns={2},
    smoothness=Modelica.Blocks.Types.Smoothness.ModifiedContinuousDerivative)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-122,14},{-102,34}})));
equation 
  connect(inertia.flange_b, bearingFriction.flange_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-20,24},{-4,24}}, color={0,0,0}));
  connect(bearingFriction.flange_b, idealGear.flange_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{16,24},{36,24}}, color={0,0,0}));
  connect(idealGear.flange_b, inertia1.flange_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{56,24},{74,24}}, color={0,0,0}));
  connect(position.flange, inertia.flange_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-62,24},{-40,24}}, color={0,0,0}));
  connect(continuousClock.y, combiTable1Ds.u)
    annotation (Line(points={{-139,24},{-124,24}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(combiTable1Ds.y[1], position.phi_ref)
    annotation (Line(points={{-101,24},{-84,24}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (
    uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")),
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent={{-160,-100},{100,100}})),
    Icon(coordinateSystem(extent={{-160,-100},{100,100}})));
end Test;
```

[Image of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEV4l.png)

Comment: Hi @simone, could you add the corresponding code of the model you try to simulate, so we can better understand the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I modified the question to tackle my real issue and shared an easy model to understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

If you ignore the `idealGear` and `inertia1` the problem becomes clearer:

You have a rigid motion of the `inertia` - and you want to compute friction, but the friction cannot influence the motion of the `inertia`.

The solutions I can see are:

- Don't give a rigid position for the inertia - use a torque-source or a attach a SpringDamper between the position-source and inertia.
- Perhaps you wanted a clutch instead of bearing-friction?

Comment: Moreover, replacing the `Position` block by a `Torque` one, coupled with an `AngleSensor` and a PI controller, would bring you closer to the real-life actuator that sets your robotic arm in motion.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use position as input. I think I will calculate the friction torque using a function, and I will add it to the flange with a `Torque`. My mistake was thinking that Modelica would have done the same with the component `bearingFriction`. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Rigid motion of friction elements is a common problem that happens from time to time in simulations. We implemented a draft to solve the issue with an inertial approach in the friction element. You can find the explanation in a pull request for the Modelica Standard Library: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/pull/4272

I just tested your model with the `BearingFriction` from the pull request, set `J_inv_fixed=1e-15` and the simulation runs fine.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This was very helpful and worked for every trajectory.